# How to get authorization code from google oauth2?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I got a task to perform google authentication. My task is like i should create a sign in with google button and after clicking it the authentication process should start and shows my details in the next view. I wrote code like this.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email%20profile&response_type=code&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oauth2.example.com/token&redirect_uri=someuri:/oauth2redirect&client_id=myclient id")!
```

and for the button i wrote function like

```
@IBAction func googleSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

I dont know how to get to get the authorization code so that i can send it back to get the access token. I sould not follow any steps provided in google to integrate my with google sign in also i should not use any pods. Anyone worked on it? please help me.

Comment: Go through this http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-google-signin-sdk-in-ios-application-using-swift

Comment: @KushalShrestha i should not do like this i should manually do everything, i should pass the client id and get the authorization code.